# Moves files into new subfolder for each year/month

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move all files under each `subfolder` into another folder with `subfoldername_mmm_yyyy` name.

Below codes only move all files in all sub folders into one folder with the name `subfoldername_subfoldername_mmm_yyyy`.

I know my for each loops are incorrect but I don't know how to fix them, would someone please help?

```
$curr_date = Get-Date
$folder_path = "C:\Logs\"
$file_type = "C:\Logs\*.log*"
$destination = "C:\Archive\"

# delete tmp files if existed
$deletefile = Get-ChildItem $destination -recurse -include *.7z.tmp -force | remove-item

# set min age of files
$max_days = "-1"

# determine how far back we go based on current date
$zip_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -eq "Directory" } | foreach {
    # obtain all subfolders
    $servername = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path | Where-Object { $_.Attributes -eq "Directory" }

    # move all files into servername_mmm_yyyy folder
    Get-ChildItem $file_type -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}| foreach {
        $x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()
        $month_year = Get-Date $x -Format MMM_yyyy
        $file_destination = ($destination) + ($servername) + "_" + ($month_year)
        if (test-path $file_destination) { 
            move-item $_.fullname $file_destination 
        }
        else {
            new-item -ItemType directory -Path $file_destination
            move-item $_.fullname $file_destination 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the parent directory instead of every file on its own?

Comment: I only need to move the .log files.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`Get-ChildItem $file_type -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)} ...`
to
`Get-ChildItem $file_type -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) -and $_.Name.EndsWith(".log")}`
and that should get you just the files you want to target

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you please help me with moving the files to folders as I described above too? Thanks again.

Comment: Once you get all the log files you want inside of your loop, the rest of the code looks like it would work as you need

Comment: I tried and it did not work. But I figured out the problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. Here is how I do it.

I just need to obtain the folder name of each file and build the destination path. Therefore, I only need one foreach loop.

```
# move all files into servername_mmm_yyyy folder
Get-ChildItem $file_path -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $zip_date) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)}| foreach {

$x = $_.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()

$month_year = Get-Date $x -Format MMM_yyyy

$servername = $_.Directory.Name

$file_destination = ($destination)+($servername)+"_"+($month_year)

if (test-path $file_destination){ 
        copy-item $_.fullname $file_destination 
    } 
    else {
        new-item -ItemType directory -Path $file_destination
        copy-item $_.fullname $file_destination 
    }
}
```